# Who is meant by Auntie Malka in friday night Zemiros?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

When eating recently by a chassidish family, I noticed they sang Friday night the words:

`אנת הוא מלכא` - 'Auntie Malka'

Can anyone shed some light on who this special Aunt was and what she is doing in the Zemiros of Shabbos?

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: Vote to close as too localized. :-p

Comment: @SethJ why, dont we all have an Auntie Malka :)

Comment: I've got a cousin...

Comment: @SethJ that is how Shidduchim start

Comment: @SethJ Galitzia is no longer a locality. The Holy Communities (Comyeenities?) of Poland and Galitzia are now on every other street corner in boro park.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

We bring our uncle along to welcome in his bride (l'cha dodi, likrat kala - go my uncle, welcome the bride)

So now it's Shabbat and they are married, you welcome your new auntie malka.

Comment: Very creative +1

Answer (score 10):

You have to listen to the line in context. It's a plan for a potluck: who brings what:

> Curry bone o' lamb, veal: Maya.
>   Auntie Malka: Mallomar.
>   Chaya:

Note that Chaya hasn't been assigned anything. This is because she drew up the list. So to answer your question, Auntie Malka is a good pastry cook. (And Chaya is a delegator, and Maya is a [*freier*](http://bogieworks.blogs.com/treppenwitz/2007/10/waste-my-time-s.html).) This *Shabas* song is very similar to another:

> *L'his'aneg b'saanugim barburim uslav v'dagim.*
>   Enjoying ourselves with good food: fattened fowl, quail, and fish.

Answer (score 3):

I humbly suggest you interpreted it incorrectly.  It says "Aint he the king?" Its a rhetorical question.

Comment: since when do chassidishe people say "aint"??

Answer (score 1):

Auntie Malka is a reference to the author of the *zemer*. The beginning of the *zemer* says:

"You're ribbon oilam ... Auntie Malka"

Auntie Malka is the one that "ties" the whole zemer together.

Answer (score 0):

The reading of the other answers is incorrect - the middle word is clearly "Hu," meaning "He." The proper question is why are we calling your Aunt a "He?"

Clearly, this deep zemer is grappling with issues of gender identity. The writer is correcting a guest in his home who has mistakenly referred to a family member by the wrong name - his Uncle Melech is now his ***Aunt Malka!***

The songwriter continues to refer to his Aunt as a "He," implying one of three things:

1. His aunt is still pre-gender reassignment surgery
2. The term "he/hu" was intended to be read in a sarcastic manner to underscore the incorrectness of the guest.
3. The author is providing a deep kabbalistic insight into the concept of dichar vinukva vis a vis those in the LGBTQ crowd.

I leave the process of discerning between these options as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: In Chassidish pronunciation, it is pronounced "he".

Comment: Chassidish pronunciation would also lead to us telling others "Sanctify me! glorify me!" - Kaddishihi Romemihi!

Comment: Seriously? what's with the downvotes?! It's Purim Torah!

Comment: They're not mine, but probably someone didn't find it very funny.

Comment: @Cnsersmoit is there someone here with a transgendered relative?